# Split a sentence (string) at the spaces

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to split a single string, with spaces, into three separate strings. For example, I have one string (str1). The user inputs any 3 words such as 
`"Hey it's me"` or `"It's hot out"`. 
From there, I need to write a function that will take this string (str1) and divide it up into three different strings. So that (taking the first example) it will then say:

```
Hey (is the first part of the string)
it's (is the second part of the string)
me (is the third part of the string)
```

I'm having difficulty which manipulation I should be using to split the string at the spaces.

This is the code I have so far, which is just how the user will enter input.I am looking for the most basic way to accomplish this **WITHOUT** using `istringstream`! Using only basic string manipulation such as find(), substr().

** I am looking to create a **separate** function to perform the breaking up of string ** I figured out how to get the first section of input with this code:

```
cout << "Enter a string" << endl;
getline(cin, one);

position = str1.find(' ', position);
first_section = str1.substr(0, position);
```

But now I have no idea how to get the second section or the third section of the string to be divided up into their own string. I was thinking a for loop maybe?? Not sure.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string str1;
   cout << "Enter three words: ";
   getline(cin, str1);
   while(cin) {
        cout << "Original string: " << str1 << endl;
        cin >> str1;
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: Would you consider using a C function to do that? E.g. `strtok`?

Comment: I'm strictly using c++ only

Comment: There are many posts on how to split a string in C++, and the easiest one doesn't need you to write a specialized function to do it.  That way is to use a `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having difficulty which manipulation I should be using to split the string at the spaces.

1. Use a `std::istringstream` from `str1`.
2. Read each of the tokens from the `std::istringstream`.

---

```
// No need to use a while loop unless you wish to do the same
// thing for multiple lines.
// while(cin) {

    cout << "Original string: " << str1 << endl;
    std::istringstream stream(str1);
    std::string token1;
    std::string token2;
    std::string token3;

    stream >> token1 >> token2 >> token3;

    // Use the tokens anyway you wish
// }
```

---

If you wish to do the same thing for multiple lines of input, use:

```
int main() {
   string str1;
   cout << "Enter three words: ";
   while(getline(cin, str1))
   {
      cout << "Original string: " << str1 << endl;
      std::istringstream stream(str1);
      std::string token1;
      std::string token2;
      std::string token3;

      stream >> token1 >> token2 >> token3;

      // Use the tokens anyway you wish

      // Prompt the user for another line
      cout << "Enter three words: ";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most basic solution is to use that which resides *inside of your loop* to *read a single word*. For example:

```
cin >> word1;       // extracts the first word
cin >> word2;       // extracts the second word
getline(cin, line); // extracts the rest of the line
```

You can use the *result* or *return value* of these expressions to check success:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::string word1, word2, line;
    int success = std::cin >> word1 && std::cin >> word2
                                    && !!std::getline(std::cin, line); // double-! necessary?
    if (success) { std::cout << "GOOD NEWS!"  << std::endl; }
    else         { std::cout << "bad news :(" << std::endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively, in such a string I would expect two spaces. My suggestion would be to use [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to locate the first and second spaces like so:

```
size_t first_position  = str1.find(' ', 0);
```

You should probably check this against `string::npos` as an opportunity to handle errors. Following that:

```
size_t second_position = str1.find(' ', first_position + 1);
```

Next error handling check and after that, it should then be trivial to use [`string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to split that string into sections like so:

```
string first_section  = str1.substr(0              , first_position)
     , second_section = str1.substr(first_position , second_position)
     , third_section  = str1.substr(second_position, string::npos);
```

Comment: for some reason when i go to store the first_position in the first_section string, I get an error that says: [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::substr(int, std::string&)'

Comment: @Alyssa Would you mind providing some code to demonstrate that problem? It seems like you're calling something like `str1.substr(0, some_string);` where `some_string` is the cause of the error; you need to provide an *integral* (`size_t`, specifically) value. That's just a guess, though, and I can't validate or invalidate it without the code you're having problems with...

Answer (score 0):

I have this Utility class that has a bunch of methods for string manipulation. I will show the class function for splitting strings with a delimiter. This class has private constructor so you can not create an instance of this class. All the methods are static methods.

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_h

// Library Includes Here: vector, string etc.

class Utility {
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit,
                                                 const std::string& strDelimiter,
                                                 const bool keepEmpty = true );

private:
    Utility();
};
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, 
                                               const std::string& strDelimiter, 
                                               const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;    
}
```

**Main.cpp** -- Usage

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Utility.h"

int main() {
    std::string myString( "Hello World How Are You Today" );

    std::vector<std::string> vStrings = Utility::splitString( myString, " " );

    // Check Vector Of Strings
    for ( unsigned n = 0; n < vStrings.size(); ++n ) {
        std::cout << vStrings[n] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // The Delimiter is also not restricted to just a single character
    std::string myString2( "Hello, World, How, Are, You, Today" );

    // Clear Out Vector
    vStrings.clear();

    vStrings = Utility::splitString( myString2, ", " ); // Delimiter = Comma & Space

    // Test Vector Again
    for ( unsigned n = 0; n < vStrings.size(); ++n ) {
        std::cout << vStrings[n] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```